# Sympy: substitute list of symbols with list of values in list of expressions

Tags: sympy, substitution

I have a list of expressions

```
Fa = [F0, F1, ... Fn]
```

, containing expressions like

```
F0 = 2*x0 + 5*x1 - x2
F1 = 3*x0 - x1
```

, with sympy symbols

```
SymList = [x0, x1, ... xn]
```

Now I have a list of values that I would like to "respectively" substitute into the symbols such as

```
ValList = [6, 19, ... 2]
```

, so that x0 is replaced by 6, x1 is replaced by 19 and so on, in each expression. How would one accomplish this?

I have tried

```
res = [[expr.subs({sym:val}) for expr in Fa] for sym, val in zip(SymList,ValList)]
```

, but this yields a list of lists with only one symbol substituted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will create a Tuple of expressions with the values replaced.

```py
from sympy import Tuple
Tuple(*Fa).xreplace(dict(zip(SymList, ValList)))
```

If you want a `list`, then apply `list` to the result.

Comment: This was indeed the solution I was looking for. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've managed to get it done but I hope there is a more elegant way.

```
resList = [Fa]
for i in range(len(SymList)):
    resList[-1] = [expr.subs({SymList[i]:ValList[i]}) for expr in resList[-1]]
```